# Как изменить значение в классе, который содержится в Map?

Tags: java, android

Есть класс

```
MyClass, который содержит массив int[] ar = new int[20]
```

Есть Map

```
Map<Integer, MyClass> myMap
myMap = new HashMap();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) myClass.ar[i] = i;
myMap.put(0, myClass)
```

Если в дальнейшем я пытаюсь изменить значения массива, вот так:

```
myMap.get(0).ar[5] = 12;
```

то не всегда новое значение присваивается. Почему? И как правильно надо менять значения полей класса, который в карте?

Comment: ну так то должно работать. наверное вы нам не всё показали

Comment: Я передаю myMap в другой класс через метод void Second(Map<Integer, MyClass> m) и потом меняю значения полей класса, который в Map. Но когда я пытаюсь считать значения полей из класса этой карты, оказывается, что они не изменились.

Comment: Приведите код передачи, может вы создаете новый объект

Comment: Я понял в чем была ошибка. Map был создан в 2х разных классах, поэтому возникла путаница.